# SmartGit - Select all files across multiple commits

Tags: smartgit

I'm looking for a way in SmartGit to select all files across multiple commits. In essence, I need a list of every file that has changed between commit A and commit C, including the files from commit B. I was also looking for a way to copy the relative file path of every changed file, but the file view only allows the option to select the relative file path when only a single file is selected. As soon as I select more than one file, my ability to copy their file paths disappears.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the commits A and C in log window. In the Files list you can see all files. Then press Ctrl-C.

Comment: Actually, as soon as I select more than one commit, the file window goes blank and the file change count disappears. That's what has me scratching my head over this, as that's the way I would presume it to work.

Comment: Select only two commits, not more.

Comment: I have the same problem of the changes windows going blank as soon as I select the second commit (using Ctrl left-mouse). Maybe it is a SmartGit version issue? I'm using version 6.5.

Comment: Maybe this problem is only related to mercurial repositories. I was originally using a mercurial repo, but I just tried it on a git repo and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm on a git repo and selecting any more than 1 commit does not work.